# Paperclip timestamp adds wrong sign after filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, timestamp, paperclip

When I'm using the Paperclip gem and showing an image with image_tag, it automatically timestamps the image (like image.jpg%343289472) but it does so using a percentage sign (%) instead of a question mark (?), and thus my browser fails to actually render the image. I have to forcefully add timestamp: false to get it to working. Does anyone know why Paperclip acts this way?

Comment: One of recent commits on paperclip produced the bug
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1706
Temporary solution is to switch to previous version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using the delayed_paperclip gem. Older versions of the delayed_paperclip gem were causing issues with monkey patching the url generator in paperclip. This was causing the % sign instead of the ? in the url you posted above.

Update **delayed_paperclip** to at least version **2.9.1**